# Window ResizeMode bind to Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I would like to permit the user to change the Window `ResizeMode` property, set by default in my case to `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`. How could it be switched to `ResizeMode="CanResize"`?

I think it could be done by creating a Boolean (or a `CheckBox.IsChecked` property) bound to `ResizeMode` with a converter, but I'm not sure if that's the way. Even if it was the right option I don't know how to create a converter that converts "`True`" to "`CanResize`" and "`False`" to "`CanMinimize`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer a Trigger solution

```
<Window>
    <CheckBox Name="checkbox" Content="CanResize" />
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkbox}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResize" />
                </DataTrigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

Comment: The idea is great but I don't have the checkbox in the same window but in the "Options" menu. I will try to use the converter. Thanks

Comment: You can bind to anything. For me the point is that it is simpler and clearer to read and code than with a converter.

Comment: Sorry I was too blind to see it, worked very well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a converter is pretty simple right.

Have something like:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class ResizeModeConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return (bool)value ? ResizeMode.CanResize : ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and add this converter to your App.xaml Resources(Converter should be in a scope available to your `Window`)

```
<Application.Resources>
  <local:ResizeModeConverter x:Key="ResizeModeConverter" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Now in your `Window`

```
<Window ... ResizeMode="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource ResizeModeConverter}}">
```

Now when `SomeProperty` is set to true or false you get your required behavior. You can set the property in your VM at startup after reading your local setting's or modify it at runtime and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, very appreciated, but I have a strange error after implementing it: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '7' and line position '101'. That line is where I set the binding of ResizeMode and the converter.

Comment: Sorry I pressed "Enter" and the comment was added. Could it be the initialization of the property? But, I had no problems with other settings that I've bound. I'm using this syntax:  ResizeMode="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MySettings.Default}, Path=resize, Converter={StaticResource ResizeModeConverter}}" >